# <bound method Class.fn> vs. <bound method fn>

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

```py
def print_a(cls):
    print(cls.a)

class Printer(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 4
        Printer.print_a = print_a

    def print_b(self):
        print(self.b)
```

```py
>> p = Printer()
>> print(p.print_a)
<bound method print_a of <__main__.Printer object at 0x000002D92C2D0288>>
>> print(p.print_b)
<bound method Printer.print_b of <__main__.Printer object at 0x000002D92C2D0288>>
```

What is the difference between the two? I understand `print_b` is dedicated to `Printer`, whereas `print_a` is a standalone function - my question concerns any *behavioral* differences between the two. The goal is to assign methods declared in different modules to a single class, and then to inherit that class (not shown) - is this accomplished?

(For a bit more context, see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242092/multiple-inheritance-of-class-broken-up-into-modules); above is to be an improvement to my approach there.)

Comment: The main behavior difference is that for bound methods of a class the `self` argument is implicitly pass to any methods not decorated as `@staticmethod`.

Comment: You could also do `import functools` and then replace `Printer.print_a = print_a` with `self.print_a = functools.partial(print_a, self)`

Comment: @CoryKramer That's true of `print_a`, but I refer to `p.print_a`, to which `self` _is_ implicitly passed; `p.print_a` is a bound method. If I decorate `print_a` with `staticmethod`, then `self` isn't passed.

Comment: `Printer.print_a` doesn't even exist until you have an instance of the class!

Comment: Other commenters seem to be overlooking that it is `Printer.print_a` being assigned to, and not `self.print_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to assign methods declared in different modules to a single class, and then to inherit that class (not shown) - is this accomplished?

It does; however, you repeat the assignment for each instantiation of the class, which is unnecessary and does not reflect your intent. (It also means that you can't do anything with `Printer.print_a` until the first time it is instantiated; this may not be relevant to you, but is an unnecessary limitation.) It would be better to just do this within the class:

```
class Printer: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 4

    def print_b(self):
        print(self.b)

    # This seems like it should do nothing, but works because of
    # how the Python scoping rules work.
    print_a = print_a
```

The code should be functionally the same as if you had defined the method normally - it will be found in the same way by the same lookup process. However, I would rather name the parameter `self` (since that parameter will indeed receive an instance, rather than the class object itself). The reason it looks different in the debug `print` is that this representation of the function relies on its `__qualname__` attribute, which is set when the function object is first created (and does not depend on where it is referred to or accessed from).

Comment: FWIW, IIRC it does not work so cleanly in 2.x, with either old-style or new-style classes. Unfortunately, I have only a vague recollection, no details at all.

Comment: Actually the printed representation depends on the `__qualname__` attribute.  If it depended on `__name__` they would look similar.

Comment: Interesting insights; is there a possibility to somehow reference or import `Printer` _without_ `Printer.print_a` being defined (i.e. line at bottom not executing)? It helps to be sure no parts are "lost in transport".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - you could put `print_a = print_a` in the class definition outside of the method.

Comment: @tdelaney Also integrated this suggestion. It looks weird, but the concern about keeping things "together" seems valid, and it does do the trick.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This looks perfect, thank you. I'll keep the question open a little in case anyone chips in a caveat.

Comment: @tdelaney Is there a way to do `print_a = print_a` programmatically? Something like `setattr(...)` to feed a list of method names to.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon -yes, `my_print_fctn  = print_a; setattr(Printer, "print_a", my_print_fctn)` works, but you couldn't do it at class scope (because the class object itself hasn't been bound to a variable name yet).

Comment: Yes, you can just have a loop that calls `setattr`; but because the thing you want to `setattr` of is `Printer`, you won't be able to do it inside `Printer` - because the name isn't defined yet. Pretty straightforward, though: supposing you draw the functions from a module named `implementation`, something like `for name in ...: setattr(Printer, name, getattr(implementation, name))`.

Comment: @tdelaney Hm, so we're back to the "lost in transport" consideration, but this does work, thanks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Your last code blob is exactly what I had in mind; is "lost in transport" really of concern, though? Suppose the entire file just contains `import implementation` and `Printer` along the `setattr` at bottom, and nothing afterwards. I could open another question